# repetition of descriptive phrase

Tags: repetition, post-modifier

The man in yellow clothes seems nice. ....(Some more sentences not including any other men)...... And (A) the man (in yellow clothes) has a Bugari.

If it is certain that the listener will understand who is 'the man' when the speaker only says 'the man' at Point A, it is OBLIGATORY that I not use 'in yellow clothes', or is it just that It is EFFICIENT that I not use 'in yellow clothes'?

Answer (score 1):

This is a style question. In English, it is not obligatory to omit the repetition of a description, but there should be some reason to repeat it when it isn't necessary. The reason could be esthetic, in poetry, or rhetorical, in a speech. If the repetition occurs at the beginning of sentences or phrases, it is called "anaphora":

[American Heritage Dictionary "anaphora"](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=anaphora)
"1. The deliberate repetition of a word or phrase at the beginning of several successive verses, clauses, or paragraphs; for example,
*'We shall fight on the beaches, we shall fight on the landing grounds, we shall fight in the fields and in the streets, we shall fight in the hills'* (Winston S. Churchill)."